# How to scale an image down efficiently?

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I have a source image, assume `2600x2600`. I want to scale this image down to verious sizes in a loop: `2000, 1500, 1000, 500, 100, 50, 10`.

Question: is it faster to scale all these images down from the *source* image of 2600px? Or should I reuse each incremental downscaled image?

Pseudecode is as follows:

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, ..);
image.getGraphics().drawImage(src, 0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight, null);
ImageIO.write(image, ...);
```

Comment: Scale from the source each time. Otherwise I imagine you will get accumulated rounding errors as you go, and should get much worse results.

Comment: Depends on what is "better". For quality it is certainly optimal to downscale the original. For speed it might be better to downscale intermediate results, but not too many times. E.g. 2600 -> 1500 -> 100, 2600 -> 2000 -> 1000 -> 50, 2600 -> 500 -> 10.

Comment: I'm mainly looking for improved speed performance. But *why* would it be better to downscale only 3 times as in your example?

Comment: Have you considered using ImgSclr or Thumbnailator or similar library? I think the most commonly accepted/used technique is scaling in halves as many times as possible using a simple algorithm (ie. linear interpolation), then do the final step in high quality (cubic, lanczos etc)..

Comment: @haraldK I'm using `ImgSclr`, but under the hood the code above still applies. The same question would be: would I use `imgSclr.resize()` using always the source image, or the downscaled images recursively?

Comment: For speed, certainly having a *smaller input image will be faster*, so always use the result of the previous operation makes sense. But as pointed out, rounding errors would increase. This may or may not be an issue for you, you must decide. From what I wrote above about halves, I think scaling from 2600 -> 1500 then 2600 -> 2000 -> 1000 -> 500 then 2600 (or perhaps use the 500) -> 100 -> 50 would be a quite okay compromise. For better quality, use some intermediate steps: 2600 -> 2000 and 1500, 1300 -> 1000, 650 -> 500, 325 -> 100, 50 and 10.